# How to update html file from native app using Phone gap in IOS

Tags: iphone, cordova

Im doing a project with PhoneGap.
1.The first view will be webView using Phonegap. 
2.the links in the webview should redirect to native App

My request is: When the native app is used, the updates should be loaded in the WebView. Can any one tell me how to do it from native app updating webview.

Comment: which plattform are you targeting?

Comment: in iphone, sorry for not mentioning.....

Answer (score 0):

You can execute javascript that will update the HTML loaded in the webview, check out

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

in UIWebView, here you can inject javascript that will update your html.
`[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert('JS Alert')"];` would show a normal alert dialog.